# i tried to reverse go2d hel1o has input and got olleh dooog but is it possible to get hello goood

Tags: java

```
package adc;

import java.util.*;

public class bca {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence to decrypt");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        int len = s.length();
        char[] ans = s.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("len=" + s.length());
        for (int i = ans.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i > 0 && ans[i] >= '0' && ans[i] <= '9') {
                char prev = ans[i - 1];
                int count = ans[i] - '0';
                for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                    out.append(prev);
                }
            } else {
                out.append(ans[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("output=" + out);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

**in this code i tried to reverse a in put in words but the charactors are reversed**
*Here i Input Go2d Hel1o* *it outputs olleH doooG but i need this to be Hello Goood*

Answer (score 0):

```
   `String fin[]=out.toString().split(" ");
    String decryptedstr="";
    for(int i=fin.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        decryptedstr = decryptedstr + fin[i] + " ";
    }
    System.out.println("Final decrypted value ="+decryptedstr);`
```

**this code helps to reverse the world**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).